# Advice - react native app with laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, http, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to ask your opinion that what would be the optimal solution to the following problem.

Our idea is to use to develop a mobile app react native, which will be linked to a web application with a built backend on the php framework Laravel.

Imagine a mobile app that users should sign in to. Once logged in, the user will be able to start the timer and the app will track the user's location from the start of the timer to the stop. We assume a minimum of 200 logged-in users at a time, assuming 200 users will be running a timer at a time. Our goal is to get data to the web application as soon as possible after the timer.

The question is whether the server can handle a load of concurrent requests, assuming, for example, that X users end up in a timer at the same time.

What would be a suitable solution for data transmission and storage.
It is sufficient to transfer over HTTPS or it is better to use WebSockets.
Would it be a good idea to use a real-time database for GPS locations with links to Laravel and the app?

Thank you.

Comment: 200 users isn't a lot, but really your question needs a lot of elaboration, how often are you going to be sending requests to the server whilst the timer is running, do you know the name of the service you'd be looking at using for tracking the user?

Comment: It's better to use `firebase` for authentication . And authenticate users via firebase and then you can use Laravel API's for other calls.

Comment: 200 users are the lower limit, I suppose at least 5,000 over time. I want users' locations to be recorded every 200-500 meters, with the data being stored in the phone memo when the timer is running. After the timer is finished, the data should be sent to the database immediately. Here the question arises as to whether it is enough for HTTP or rather to solve the transfer via WebSockets due to possible competing requests. The goal is to save as much as possible at third party services like Firebase and Pubnub. Data will be sent when the running timer is over. It can be in 10 seconds or 8 hours

Comment: I thought of solving the authentication and saving of locations and timers in Firebase and then connecting Firebase with the Laravel API.
The application will also have sections other than adding various tasks, events that I would link directly to the Laravel API without using Firebase.
The question is whether it is appropriate to combine MySQL with Firebase. Thanks